# Escape character from URL encoding

Tags: url, url-encoding

URL encoding replaces reserved characters with `%..`.

Is it possible to prevent URL encoding from changing a character? E.g. that `&` doesn't become a `%26` but still is a `&` after the encoding?

Comment: URL encoding does not happen magically. You can indeed submit HTTP request with any URI you can figure out, including blatantly malformed ones (whether the server will accept them or not is another story). What piece of software / programming language are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You need to render the url as utf-8
**This type of encoding doesn't fact anything.** It just make problem read the url.